# cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) Error After Finish Playing Video

Tags: python, opencv

I want to read an existing video, convert it to grayscale and play the grayscale video. The code is as follows

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.avi')

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # convert it into grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The grayscale video plays until the end. When it's done playing- the following error pops up-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\L1.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Why this error is showing? Is there any solution for that?

I am using python 3.6 and opencv 3.4

Comment: I love that the OpenCV tutorials all get the return value from `cap.read()`, but then don't bother to check it. After you've read the last frame, your program loops back and tries to read another frame. There's not one there, so it returns `None` for `frame` and `False` for the boolean `ret`. Checking either one of those and breaking out of the loop if one of them is detected will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is going to continue to try to get frames after the video has finished.  You can check if the `cap` returned an image or else break like shown below.  Also, don't forget to release the video.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        # convert it into grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You should submit this [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html). It is *far* better than their version and would certainly save a lot of trouble for people trying to follow the tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, will do.  But strange, I see they check the `ret` in the "Saving a Video" section, just not in the "Playing Video from file".  I wonder if the `while(cap.isOpened()):` used to be sufficient.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `cap.isOpened()` will still be true even after the last frame  is read (and until `cap.release()` is called), so you still need to check `ret`. And I had not noticed that they code it differently for saving the video. That's funny. :)